# I'm trying to find the eigenvalues of a matrix. What is my mistake?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix:
$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
3 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 & 3
    \end{array}
\right]$
 which I rewrote as 
$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
λ-3 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & λ-2 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & λ-3
    \end{array}
\right]$. Then, I calculated the determinant, and I get $(λ-3)^2(λ-2) - (λ-3)^2= (λ-3)^3 = 0$, so $λ=3$, but this is completely wrong. I should have gotten $λ^3-8λ^2+19λ-12$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Expand the determinant correctly...The error is here..

Comment: I don't see where I went wrong. Of course it must be with calculating the determinant. I used this method: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Determinant_3x3_Example.svg/440px-Determinant_3x3_Example.svg.png to find the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-3 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & \lambda-2 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix}&=(\lambda-3)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)-2(\lambda-3)\\
&=(\lambda-3)(\lambda^2-5\lambda+6-2)\\
&=(\lambda-3)(\lambda^2-5\lambda+4)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Wow, of course. I multiplied the values instead of adding them together. Thank you. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$(\lambda-1)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)=0\implies \lambda=1,3,4$

Comment: If it's characteristic equation, point to it

Answer (score 0):

The Determinant should be:

$((λ−3)^2(λ−2))-(λ−3)-(λ−3)=0$

$ (λ−3)^2(λ−2))-2(λ−3)=0$

Please see:

https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8s00/public_html/handouts/matrices3/node7.html